# Split column into range of rows

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I would like to sort the data from one column to become 2 rows of 5 columns using Google Sheets.

Does someone know how to do that?

The result should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: What the final result should look like?

Comment: @MaxMakhrov The initial result is one column and 10 rows. The final result should show 2 rows in 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. One is:

`=TRANSPOSE({OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A)/2),OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)/2,,COUNTA(A:A)/2)})`

[image]

## More general solution

To split the column into any given number of rows, use the formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
  COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/numRows)))+
  ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/numRows)*(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&numRows))-1),
{ROW(A:A),A:A},2,)))`

where `numRows` is a number of rows.

This:

`COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/numRows))) +
ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/numRows)*(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&numRows))-1)`

generates indexes:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

and `VLOOKUP(indexes,{ROW(A:A),A:A},2,)` is to return the result:

[image]

Comment: Still not working. I want the final result to show the data in 5 columns and two rows.

Comment: Wow man! Appreciated for your answer even after a long time. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

The solution should work regardless of how many values there are in the string inside the cell. Assume the cell is G4. Here goes the formula:

```
={array_constrain(split(G4, " "), 1, columns(split(G4, " "))/2);
  transpose(sort(transpose(array_constrain(transpose(sort(transpose(split(G4, " ")), 1, false)), 1, columns(split(G4, " "))/2))))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @ttarchala , but the formatting of the text had my question changed. The initial result is one column and 10 rows. The final result should show 2 rows in 5 columns.